# CircleCi 2.0 Workflow requires option is not working

Tags: yaml, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I ran into a problem where I wanted to have a sequential workflow in my CircleCi 2.0 config. I wanted to have `build->test->deploy`, and used the `requires` option, but it kept giving me a config error.

Here's an example script:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    ...
  test:
    ...
  deploy:
    ...


workflows:
  version: 2
  myapp_ci:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test:
        requires:
          - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - test
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is actually indentation...even though I ran it through a yml parser, you need a second indentation for the `requires` tag.

So

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  myapp_ci:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test:
        requires:
          - build
```

Becomes

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  myapp_ci:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test:
          requires:
            - build
```

Hopefully this saves someone else some time!

Comment: Good catch. I would run it through CircleCI's own parser called the CircleCI Local CLI.

Comment: @FelicianoTech Good idea, but that didn't help either at the time. It actually sent me down the wrong path looking at where I had a syntax error. `Error: Error parsing config file: yaml: line 70: did not find expected '-' indicator`

Comment: it still does not work. something is wrong with circle ci. this is a super critical bug. version 1.0 was superior.